# Java 8 range() of list?

Tags: java, java-8

```
for (final A a : listOfAs.getList()) {
 do something (if statement), not using a
}
```

Is there any way to improve this code in Java 8? I.e. I want to perform something as many times as how many elements are in the list, but I will not use the element a inside the loop. 
For example, python has

```
for _ in range(n):
```

Is there something similar in Java 8?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [IntStream.range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) :

```
 IntStream.range(0,listOfAs.getList().size()).forEach(i->{...});
```

This won't iterate over your list.

The `forEach` method of `IntStream` accepts an `IntConsumer`, which is a functional interface that has the method `void accept(int value)`. In my example I supplied a lambda expression that matches that interface. You do get the `int` index, whether you use it or not.

Comment: Can I put an if statement inside? When I tried I am getting an error.

Comment: @Tad I fixed the example. You can put whatever statements you want inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the famous `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listOfAs.getList().size(); i++){
}
```

This will not iterate through the elements of your list.

Comment: This uses i which I don't need.

Comment: but its simpler than Streams isnt it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Streams :

```
listOfAs.stream().forEach(Consumer c);
```